# openstack Hello World

Tags: eucalyptus, openstack

I would like to write a program on an open-stack cloud.
When I search for resources, all I find are installation and Admin manuals.

I have a cloud installed, now how do I run a program on it?
An example of using the message queue or the blob-store would be nice.

Does anyone know of a good programming tutorial for this?

Comment: Openstack helps you build your own cloud, while cloud is set of resources like database server(openstack-swift) , image storage server(openstack glance) and servers(openstack compute). All you need to do is install and reuse the space for storage effectively...!

Comment: I do not want to install. My cloud is fine, But now that I have the cloud, how do I write a program that uses it? Whenever I start programming in a new environment I download some sample code and modify it a little. The first time I learnt SQL I downloaded some SQL statements and modified them... I would like to do the same here.

Comment: Are we not confused cloud to be a programming language. It is an infra. We can configure PHP or any other language of choice and compile it on them and then definitely use those nova, swift and glance functionalities or api to store the required data as per the requirement. But yes your question is correct. We need hello world program in different languages...! I think this is a great idea, to develope a framework around for Openstack. or does Rackspace or Nasa has built in framework ready for it.!

Comment: So, yes, I guess you could say I am looking for "swift and glance " hello world functionalities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be more clear when you say 'write a program on an Openstack cloud'.

**a.**   If you mean that you want to write recipes to control and play with your VMs in an Openstack cloud, they you should consider installing and using the following packages:

- python-novaclient - client library for OpenStack Compute API
- python-nova-adminclient - client for administering Openstack Nova

The above two libraries expose everything you will need to write an application.

**b.**   If however, you are looking forward to contribute to Openstack project, they should prepare you development environment first and then register yourself on Launchpad. The code has moved to [GitHub](https://github.com) but the blueprints and bug discussions are still on [launchpad](https://launchpad.net).

Hope it helps. Let me know if you need further help in this regard.

Comment: I think that this doesn't answer the question. As you can see from the following image, an application can communicate with openstack. I'm also searching for a simple example. http://www.openstack.org/themes/openstack/images/openstack-software-diagram.png

Comment: if you knew only a little bit about OpenStack or Software in general, you would know that Application can be any kind of client. That apart my reply above clears the ambiguity in the question not just answers it.

Answer (score 1):

'Hello world' is not suitable example program for openstack.

Yes ofcourse you can setup your php dev environment in an instance and can develop programs in it. In this example you are just consuming openstack as an end user.

The real power of openstack can be recognised in this example:

You can design an application (eg: DB as a Service). In this applciation , the user just clicks a 'Request DB Instance' button and then he will be provided a 'ipaddress','port number' and credentials for his connection string. So that he can connect his application to the generated database.

In the background you can use python apis call for creating a new vm , install the os and install the required softwares (Database service) all these will be done by openstack automatically.

This is a simple example application (PAAS) which runs above Openstack.

Answer (score 0):

I made a research on your question, [Look at the API functions here i.e. object api, compute api etc apis](https://github.com/openstack), without these functionality getting finished, all the openstack is you cannot code anything programming wise. Anything you do is only you build a cloud and execute commands manually.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, the motivation behind [OpenStack](http://www.openstack.org/software/) is NOT building a server, nor API, nor a database.

OpenStack is about managing an environment of multiple machines, databases and the networking to connect them all.

For example, as I understand it, you should be able to implement a feature on your OpenStack cloud to create 10 VMs and 3 DBs. This can be created using a click on the dashboard or invoke some API.

Once a VM is up, you can install a [Linux image on it](http://docs.openstack.org/image-guide/content/). A web-server, for example, can then be deployed on that new VM, though this, I think, is unrelated to OpenStack.