# openstack first program

Tags: openstack

I have setup my openstack dev environment. Now i want to write hello world program (for example i want to write a hello world program in a file say test and when i run nova-manage test  it should print Hello World). i looked into web for programming guide, all i found was installation and admin manual. I even went through question [openstack Hello World](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8244328/openstack-hello-world) , wasn't helpful. I could use some help...

thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

So by openstack dev environment I assume you mean something like devstack ( devstack.org ).

And by openstack I assume ( since you referenced nova-manage ) you are using the nova component of openstack.

nova is a cloud compute controller.  it effectively acts as an API for managing virtual machines.  Usually in linux this means kvm or xen hypervisor enabled virtual machines.  But it is not constrained to this.

By default devstack uses kvm as it's hypervisor of choice.

Openstack will allow you to launch 'instances' once you have loaded images into the glance imagestore.  These images function like templates for virtual machines.  When you launch an instance based off an existing image you will receive a running virtual machine within your project in openstack.  You can ssh to that instance and use it just like any other linux box if the image you are using is a linux image.

Ubuntu cloud services have a list of available images that are compatible with glance and can be freely downloaded.

So... at this point in the explanation I have to assume you think that openstack is something like cloud foundry.  It is not.  Nova provides IaaS solutions.  Infrastructure as a Service.  Not PaaS / SaaS as something like cloud foundry would.

Does this make sense?